# Que veut dire « créance sur la collectivité » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Je voudrais savoir ce que veut dire l'expression « créance sur la collectivité » dans ce contexte :

> Du droit-protection, on passe à une créance sur la collectivité : c’est la prétention à obtenir d’elle tout ce qui est nécessaire pour que l’exercice de la liberté soit effectivement possible ; au lieu de demander à pouvoir agir sans contrainte, on demande à être aidé. Les libertés ne sont plus uniquement des facultés de faire – ou de ne pas faire – mais aussi des droits d’exiger de l’autorité les moyens de les exercer

Comment: La "créance" se réfère à une obligation de l'autorité publique qui "doit" assurer une liberté effective, donnant des droits, mais aussi des moyens pour en bénéficier effectivement.

Answer (score 1):

Le [créance](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A9ance) est le droit d'exiger quelque chose de quelqu'un. Donc la créance sur la collectivité est le droit d'exiger quelque chose de la collectivité. Ici, on dit qu'on passe du droit à la collectivité de nous aider (sans rien demander à personne), au droit à la personne d'exiger des choses de la collectivité.
Un individu peut donc demander à la mairie de l'aide si elle souhaite améliorer sa vie de quartier.

Comment: La dernière phrase me semble un contresens. La collectivité représente ici l'administration, l'État, pas les individus. Ce serait plutôt un particulier qui demanderait à sa mairie de repeindre les volets de sa maison.

Comment: @jlliagre En effet, ce sens semble plus logique... :)

Answer (score 1):

Dans le contexte indiqué, cela signifie que tout citoyen est en droit de demander à la collectivité :

> - tout ce qui est nécessaire pour que l’exercice de la liberté soit effectivement possible ;
> - au lieu de demander à pouvoir agir sans contrainte, on demande à être aidé.

Et la collectivité à le devoir d'y répondre. Ce n'est pas simplement laisser faire quelque chose d'autorisé mais aussi d'aider à faire ce quelque chose.